# How to remove rows from a data table based on a condition in another data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have 2 data frames:

```
master = data.table(MasterTimes= as.POSIXct("2015-01-01", tz = "GMT") + seq(1,100,1))
mydata = data.frame(MyTimes = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 00:00:18","2015-01-01 00:00:54","2015-01-01 00:00:48","2015-01-01 00:01:10","2015-01-01 00:01:05"),tz = "GMT"))
```

I would like to keep any rows in master within +/- 5 second window of **any** time in the `mydata` data frame.  I would like to remove the rows in `master` that do not meet that condition.

Here is a simpler example if `mydata` only has 1 rows:

```
master = data.table(MasterTimes= as.POSIXct("2015-01-01", tz = "GMT") + seq(1,100,1))
mydata = data.frame(MyTimes = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 00:00:18"),tz = "GMT"))
```

You can see `mydata` only contains `"2015-01-01 00:00:18"`. In this case I want to remove all the rows from the master data frame where the time is not within the +- 5 second window i.e I want to remove all rows from `master` before `"2015-01-01 00:00:13"` and after `"2015-01-01 00:00:23"`

Thats the simple case but a harder case is if mydata contains

```
   mydata = data.frame(MyTimes = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 00:00:18", "2015-01-01 00:00:22"),tz = "GMT"))
```

In this case because `"2015-01-01 00:00:18"` is there again I would normally remove all the rows in master before `"2015-01-01 00:00:13"` and after `"2015-01-01 00:00:23"`.

But in this case I can't do that because `mydata` also contains `"2015-01-01 00:00:22"` so I want to keep all the rows in `master` after `"2015-01-01 00:00:18"` and before `"2015-01-01 00:00:27"`

Because `"2015-01-01 00:00:22"` is in my data I now need to keep the rows in master from `"2015-01-01 00:00:23"` to `"2015-01-01 00:00:27"`

Basically I want to keep any row in master that is within a +/- 5 second window of every row in `mydata`.  If there are any rows in master that are **not** within a 5 second window  I want to delete it.

## Update

Can you advise how to implement this if `master` and `mydata` have more than 1 column like:

```
master = data.table(MasterTimes= as.POSIXct("2015-01-01", tz = "GMT") + seq(1,100,1), otherol = seq(1,100,1))
mydata = data.frame(MyTimes = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 00:00:18"),tz = "GMT"),othercol = c(1))
```

In reality both master and mydata have 50+ columns.

Comment: I guess that `master[rowSums(abs(outer(master$MasterTimes,mydata$MyTimes,difftime,units="sec"))<=5)>0]` could be a way, but it doesn't scale well and certainly better solutions exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
check_valid_time <- function(row, mydata){
   any(row > mydata$MyTimes - 5 & row < mydata$MyTimes + 5)
}

master[sapply(master$MasterTimes, check_valid_time, mydata),]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain where the row and mydata parameter are passed to the check_valid_time function when you call sapply()?

Comment: @CatusWoman - Can you see the update in the post. How would you implent your solution with more than 1 column in the data frames. In reality master and mydata both have 50+ columns

Comment: @user3022875 This should work no matter how many columns you have (the variable is named row but it's actually just the value of `MasterTimes` for that row) Sapply is passing each value of `master$MasterTimes` to `check_valid_time`, with `mydata` as an additional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be the following. You first create `foo` which contains +/- 5 seconds of mydata$MyTimes for each row. Then, You subset `master`. First, you remove `mydata$MyTimes` and then select `foo$whatever` in MasterTimes. Just in case, I sorted the data by `MasterTimes` in the end.

```
foo <- setDT(mydata)[, list(whatever = seq(MyTimes - 5, MyTimes + 5, by  = 1)), by = rownames(mydata)]
master[!MasterTimes %in% mydata$MyTimes][MasterTimes %in% foo$whatever] -> x

setorder(x, MasterTimes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on nicola's comment:

```
master[unlist(lapply(master$MasterTimes, function(x) any(abs(difftime(x, mydata$MyTimes, units="secs"))<5) )),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
master[which(sapply(unlist(master), function(x) 
    min(sapply(unlist(mydata), function(y) abs(x - y)))) <5 ),]
```

Comment: WHy are there NAs in your output?

Comment: @user3022875 I don't get any `NA`s after running the code. Are all the values `NA`s?

Comment: the result is correct but it includes NAs at the bottom